# Applying function to specific rows using for loop R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, subset

I am having trouble to set correctly the rows that I need to pass to a function. I have "calculating functions" and "row selecting functions". The functions that I use to calculate are doing what I want. 
The function must subset first `estado=3` (that part goes fine) then subset the correct row numbers and pass them to "the calculating functions".

As I said, my code to select should pick specific row numbers (in this case 1:11, 23:23, 46:56 and 68:78). The thing is I'm trying to make this automatic for any data frame's length. I should get this pattern: rep (11 , 12) where I mean I have drop the first 11 between the first two dfs I pass to the calculating function and drop 12 between the first two and the next block and loop till the data frame is over (see photo to get better undesrstanding).

[image]

The row selecting is based on time (you can see that there's a `tiempo` column so there's a little bit of calculating rows based on times (t_muestreo, t_pasaje, t__entre). I'm trying to set the row numbers based on this times just in case we have to change them in our experiment.

```
pendientes_ensayo <- function(df){

  pendientes = data.frame()

  t_muestreo = 0.2
  t_pasaje = 2
  t_entre = 2.5

  nro_filas_salto = (t_pasaje / t_muestreo)
  nro_filas_entre = (t_entre/t_muestreo)


  df_a_medir_completo = df[df$estado == 3,] # Me quedo solo con la parte que mido

  tamanodf = dim(df_a_medir_completo)[1]
  df$tiempo = as.numeric( df$tiempo)
  cant_animales = length(names(df)) - 2 # tiempo y estado

  pos_en_filas = 1
  for(nro_ensayo in 1:(tamanodf/ (nro_filas_salto + nro_filas_entre)   )) {

    print( pos_en_filas )
    print( pos_en_filas + nro_filas_salto )

    df_a_medir = df_a_medir_completo[pos_en_filas:(pos_en_filas+nro_filas_salto),]
    pendientes = rbind(pendientes,obtener_pendientes(df_a_medir))  

    pos_en_filas = pos_en_filas + nro_filas_salto + nro_filas_entre  - 0.5

  }
  return(pendientes)
}
```

The return I get (printed rows) is this

```
[1] 1
[1] 11
[1] 23
[1] 33
[1] 45
[1] 55
[1] 67
[1] 77
```

Note that the first 2 subsets (1:11 and 23:33 are correct) but 45:55 and 67:77 are one row out of phase.

In order to run the pendientes_ensayo function you will need

```
iti = 153
t_adaptacion = 600
t_pre_estimulo = 18
t_muestreo = 0.2
t_pasaje = 2
t_entre = 2.5
defasaje = 1
nro_ensayos = 2


regresion <- function(formula){ 
  regresion = lm( formula )
  ss = summary(regresion)
  return(c( coef(regresion)[2] , ss$adj.r.squared))
}

sacar_columnas <- function (dataframe,columnas){
  return(dataframe[,!(names(dataframe) %in% columnas)])
}

desplazar<- function(tiempo,dataframe){
  matriz = as.matrix(dataframe)
  matriz_dif = abs(diff(matriz )) # derivar
  matriz_dif_inv = diffinv(matriz_dif) # integrar

  return(data.frame(cbind(tiempo, matriz_dif_inv )))
}

obtener_pendientes <- function(df_a_medir){
  df_a_medir2 =sacar_columnas(df_a_medir,  c("estado","tiempo"))
  mat_desplazamiento = desplazar(df_a_medir$tiempo,df_a_medir2)
  pend_muestreo = apply(mat_desplazamiento,2,function(x) regresion(x~df_a_medir$tiempo))  
  return(pend_muestreo)
}
```

Here's an example of a data frame that has been already subseted by df$estado=3

```
dput(d)
structure(list(estado = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), tiempo = c(618.2, 
618.4, 618.6, 618.8, 619, 619.2, 619.4, 619.6, 619.8, 620, 620.2, 
620.4, 620.6, 620.8, 621, 621.2, 621.4, 621.6, 621.8, 622, 622.2, 
622.4, 622.6, 622.8, 623, 623.2, 623.4, 623.6, 623.8, 624, 624.2, 
624.4, 624.6, 624.8, 625, 625.2, 625.4, 625.6, 625.8, 626, 626.2, 
626.4, 626.6, 626.8, 627, 3138.2, 3138.4, 3138.6, 3138.8, 3139, 
3139.2, 3139.4, 3139.6, 3139.8, 3140, 3140.2, 3140.4, 3140.6, 
3140.8, 3141, 3141.2, 3141.4, 3141.6, 3141.8, 3142, 3142.2, 3142.4, 
3142.6, 3142.8, 3143, 3143.2, 3143.4, 3143.6, 3143.8, 3144, 3144.2, 
3144.4, 3144.6, 3144.8, 3145, 3145.2, 3145.4, 3145.6, 3145.8, 
3146, 3146.2, 3146.4, 3146.6, 3146.8, 3147), UT2x45 = c(14663, 
14662, 14661, 14659, 14657, 14654, 14652, 14650, 14651, 14651, 
14651, 14650, 14648, 14647, 14645, 14644, 14641, 14640, 14640, 
14640, 14640, 14640, 14639, 14639, 14638, 14638, 14637, 14637, 
14637, 14636, 14636, 14635, 14634, 14632, 14631, 14629, 14628, 
14628, 14626, 14625, 14625, 14625, 14624, 14624, 14624, 10888, 
10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 
10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 
10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 
10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 
10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888, 10888), TR2x45 = c(14663, 
14663, 14655, 14634, 14632, 14634, 14634, 14632, 14633, 14605, 
14573, 14555, 14548, 14540, 14525, 14523, 14517, 14510, 14506, 
14499, 14497, 14494, 14492, 14487, 14453, 14426, 14414, 14416, 
14413, 14413, 14416, 14409, 14387, 14380, 14367, 14364, 14356, 
14347, 14347, 14343, 14337, 14332, 14330, 14329, 14327, 13432, 
13432, 13427, 13424, 13426, 13427, 13427, 13427, 13428, 13428, 
13426, 13424, 13423, 13423, 13423, 13423, 13423, 13422, 13421, 
13421, 13420, 13419, 13418, 13417, 13410, 13410, 13410, 13411, 
13411, 13411, 13411, 13411, 13410, 13410, 13410, 13410, 13410, 
13411, 13411, 13411, 13411, 13411, 13411, 13411, 13411), UT2x45.2 = c(15510, 
15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 
15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 
15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 
15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 
15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15510, 15282, 
15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 
15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 
15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 
15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 
15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282, 15282), TR2x45.2 = c(17295, 
17295, 17293, 17266, 17248, 17250, 17268, 17277, 17252, 17195, 
17141, 17115, 17108, 17105, 17102, 17099, 17098, 17097, 17093, 
17089, 17086, 17084, 17084, 17083, 17080, 17036, 16975, 16919, 
16884, 16869, 16836, 16788, 16738, 16700, 16675, 16661, 16653, 
16648, 16643, 16638, 16634, 16633, 16631, 16629, 16626, 24047, 
24047, 24047, 24047, 24047, 24062, 24085, 24119, 24163, 24191, 
24181, 24182, 24181, 24183, 24183, 24183, 24183, 24183, 24183, 
24183, 24183, 24184, 24184, 24184, 24182, 24137, 24070, 24011, 
23978, 23965, 23920, 23868, 23826, 23806, 23799, 23796, 23788, 
23782, 23776, 23774, 23772, 23769, 23766, 23764, 23761), TR2x45.3 = c(14702, 
14702, 14702, 14702, 14702, 14702, 14702, 14704, 14720, 14733, 
14739, 14741, 14743, 14744, 14746, 14750, 14753, 14754, 14755, 
14756, 14756, 14758, 14759, 14760, 14760, 14760, 14763, 14767, 
14770, 14774, 14773, 14774, 14775, 14775, 14776, 14776, 14776, 
14776, 14776, 14776, 14776, 14776, 14776, 14776, 14776, 14818, 
14818, 14818, 14818, 14818, 14820, 14819, 14818, 14819, 14819, 
14819, 14819, 14819, 14819, 14819, 14819, 14819, 14819, 14819, 
14819, 14819, 14819, 14819, 14819, 14817, 14816, 14816, 14816, 
14816, 14816, 14817, 14817, 14817, 14817, 14817, 14817, 14817, 
14817, 14817, 14817, 14817, 14817, 14817, 14817, 14817), UT2x45.3 = c(18521, 
18518, 18517, 18518, 18517, 18515, 18513, 18512, 18510, 18507, 
18505, 18503, 18501, 18499, 18499, 18497, 18496, 18495, 18493, 
18492, 18490, 18487, 18483, 18481, 18479, 18476, 18474, 18472, 
18471, 18470, 18467, 18464, 18461, 18457, 18455, 18453, 18451, 
18449, 18447, 18445, 18442, 18438, 18435, 18432, 18430, 18204, 
18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 
18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 
18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 
18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 
18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204, 18204), TR2x45.1 = c(14052, 
14049, 14013, 13961, 13907, 13874, 13861, 13844, 13801, 13742, 
13680, 13627, 13585, 13563, 13547, 13536, 13524, 13511, 13497, 
13487, 13477, 13466, 13457, 13446, 13406, 13352, 13295, 13255, 
13248, 13237, 13211, 13163, 13110, 13066, 13034, 13015, 13000, 
12980, 12969, 12958, 12944, 12931, 12927, 12919, 12910, 11396, 
11394, 11355, 11301, 11247, 11210, 11198, 11195, 11164, 11130, 
11081, 11038, 11011, 11003, 10991, 10982, 10974, 10966, 10960, 
10954, 10949, 10944, 10941, 10934, 10892, 10839, 10789, 10748, 
10729, 10722, 10697, 10656, 10611, 10574, 10547, 10534, 10525, 
10516, 10509, 10502, 10494, 10489, 10485, 10482, 10476), UT2x45.1 = c(17050, 
17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 
17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 
17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 
17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 
17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17050, 17077, 
17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 
17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 17077, 
17077, 17077, 17077, 17078, 17078, 17080, 17083, 17084, 17084, 
17084, 17085, 17087, 17089, 17090, 17093, 17095, 17095, 17096, 
17098, 17100, 17101, 17103, 17106, 17107, 17109, 17111), UT2x45.4 = c(16434, 
16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 
16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 
16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 
16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 
16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16434, 16823, 
16824, 16825, 16825, 16825, 16825, 16825, 16826, 16826, 16826, 
16826, 16826, 16826, 16826, 16824, 16824, 16824, 16824, 16826, 
16827, 16828, 16828, 16828, 16828, 16829, 16829, 16830, 16831, 
16832, 16832, 16832, 16832, 16833, 16833, 16834, 16835, 16834, 
16833, 16833, 16833, 16833, 16834, 16834, 16835, 16836), TR2x45.4 = c(12488, 
12488, 12486, 12471, 12448, 12435, 12430, 12423, 12418, 12370, 
12307, 12247, 12190, 12136, 12095, 12069, 12045, 12025, 12015, 
12001, 11994, 11985, 11978, 11967, 11931, 11885, 11817, 11761, 
11714, 11667, 11624, 11574, 11519, 11475, 11438, 11405, 11375, 
11354, 11330, 11313, 11303, 11284, 11272, 11265, 11255, 9056, 
9056, 9056, 9056, 9056, 9056, 9056, 9056, 9054, 9039, 9006, 8994, 
8983, 8969, 8968, 8964, 8957, 8950, 8951, 8949, 8943, 8936, 8935, 
8934, 8920, 8885, 8841, 8808, 8778, 8752, 8715, 8654, 8595, 8549, 
8524, 8500, 8488, 8477, 8461, 8458, 8447, 8441, 8436, 8426, 8421
), UT2x45.1.1 = c(12004, 12004, 12004, 12004, 12004, 12004, 12004, 
12004, 12003, 12003, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 
12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 
12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 
12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 12002, 
12002, 12002, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 
11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 
11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 
11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 
11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 11015, 
11015, 11015), TR2x45.1.1 = c(20832, 20832, 20828, 20818, 20822, 
20855, 20873, 20895, 20930, 20915, 20904, 20904, 20904, 20904, 
20904, 20904, 20904, 20904, 20905, 20906, 20907, 20908, 20911, 
20916, 20918, 20887, 20857, 20861, 20879, 20892, 20910, 20897, 
20893, 20894, 20893, 20893, 20893, 20893, 20893, 20893, 20893, 
20893, 20893, 20893, 20893, 22371, 22371, 22370, 22369, 22383, 
22410, 22440, 22459, 22470, 22426, 22414, 22406, 22404, 22404, 
22404, 22403, 22402, 22402, 22402, 22402, 22402, 22402, 22402, 
22402, 22405, 22387, 22371, 22373, 22387, 22390, 22364, 22327, 
22303, 22295, 22283, 22272, 22264, 22253, 22250, 22240, 22234, 
22232, 22230, 22223, 22214), TR2x45.5 = c(11994, 11992, 11991, 
11992, 11994, 11994, 11992, 11989, 11991, 11988, 11981, 11978, 
11978, 11977, 11974, 11971, 11971, 11969, 11962, 11955, 11952, 
11948, 11945, 11943, 11942, 11942, 11942, 11942, 11941, 11939, 
11938, 11938, 11931, 11928, 11927, 11925, 11920, 11917, 11915, 
11914, 11909, 11906, 11904, 11901, 11897, 3997, 3997, 3997, 3997, 
3997, 3997, 3997, 3997, 3997, 3997, 3998, 3998, 3998, 3998, 3998, 
3998, 3998, 3998, 3998, 3998, 3998, 3998, 3998, 3998, 3998, 3998, 
3998, 3998, 3998, 3999, 3999, 3999, 3999, 3999, 3999, 3999, 3999, 
3999, 3999, 3999, 3999, 3999, 3999, 3999, 3999), TR2x45.1.2 = c(12363, 
12363, 12352, 12332, 12333, 12330, 12329, 12329, 12329, 12318, 
12298, 12296, 12289, 12286, 12277, 12264, 12264, 12261, 12254, 
12252, 12249, 12248, 12246, 12244, 12244, 12240, 12227, 12224, 
12220, 12219, 12218, 12215, 12206, 12200, 12197, 12197, 12196, 
12196, 12195, 12191, 12187, 12183, 12182, 12179, 12177, 11923, 
11922, 11921, 11914, 11913, 11913, 11913, 11913, 11913, 11905, 
11904, 11903, 11903, 11903, 11902, 11902, 11901, 11901, 11901, 
11901, 11901, 11900, 11900, 11899, 11898, 11891, 11880, 11878, 
11875, 11873, 11871, 11870, 11866, 11864, 11861, 11859, 11857, 
11856, 11855, 11854, 11853, 11852, 11851, 11849, 11848), UT2x45.5 = c(12040, 
12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 
12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 
12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 
12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 
12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 12040, 10462, 
10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 
10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 
10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 
10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 
10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462, 10462), UT2x45.1.2 = c(12349, 
12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 
12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 
12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 
12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 
12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 12349, 9580, 
9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 
9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 
9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 
9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580, 9580
), UT2x45.6 = c(15564, 15563, 15562, 15562, 15563, 15563, 15563, 
15563, 15562, 15562, 15560, 15554, 15544, 15542, 15541, 15540, 
15539, 15538, 15538, 15537, 15536, 15535, 15533, 15529, 15528, 
15525, 15524, 15521, 15519, 15517, 15516, 15516, 15515, 15515, 
15514, 15514, 15513, 15510, 15508, 15505, 15502, 15501, 15500, 
15498, 15496, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 
12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 
12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 
12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 
12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 12438, 
12438, 12438), UT2x45.1.3 = c(18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 
18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 
18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18966, 18967, 18968, 18968, 
18969, 18970, 18970, 18971, 18971, 18971, 18972, 18973, 18974, 
18974, 18975, 18976, 18977, 18977, 18978, 18978, 18978, 18978, 
18979, 18980, 18980, 18981, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 
20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 
20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 
20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 
20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 20189, 
20189, 20189, 20189, 20189), TR2x45.6 = c(15834, 15834, 15834, 
15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 
15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 
15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 15834, 
15834, 15834, 15834, 15835, 15835, 15835, 15835, 15835, 15835, 
15835, 15835, 15835, 15835, 15835, 15835, 16775, 16775, 16775, 
16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 
16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 
16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 
16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 
16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775, 16775), TR2x45.1.3 = c(19716, 
19716, 19716, 19716, 19716, 19718, 19718, 19718, 19720, 19722, 
19723, 19723, 19723, 19723, 19723, 19723, 19722, 19722, 19722, 
19723, 19723, 19723, 19724, 19724, 19725, 19726, 19728, 19730, 
19732, 19733, 19736, 19737, 19737, 19737, 19737, 19738, 19738, 
19738, 19738, 19738, 19738, 19738, 19738, 19738, 19738, 27720, 
27720, 27720, 27720, 27720, 27720, 27720, 27720, 27720, 27720, 
27720, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 
27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 
27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 
27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719, 27719)), .Names = c("estado", 
"tiempo", "UT2x45", "TR2x45", "UT2x45.2", "TR2x45.2", "TR2x45.3", 
"UT2x45.3", "TR2x45.1", "UT2x45.1", "UT2x45.4", "TR2x45.4", "UT2x45.1.1", 
"TR2x45.1.1", "TR2x45.5", "TR2x45.1.2", "UT2x45.5", "UT2x45.1.2", 
"UT2x45.6", "UT2x45.1.3", "TR2x45.6", "TR2x45.1.3"), row.names = c("3087", 
"3088", "3089", "3090", "3091", "3092", "3093", "3094", "3095", 
"3096", "3097", "3098", "3099", "3100", "3101", "3102", "3103", 
"3104", "3105", "3106", "3107", "3108", "3109", "3110", "3111", 
"3112", "3113", "3114", "3115", "3116", "3117", "3118", "3119", 
"3120", "3121", "3122", "3123", "3124", "3125", "3126", "3127", 
"3128", "3129", "3130", "3131", "15687", "15688", "15689", "15690", 
"15691", "15692", "15693", "15694", "15695", "15696", "15697", 
"15698", "15699", "15700", "15701", "15702", "15703", "15704", 
"15705", "15706", "15707", "15708", "15709", "15710", "15711", 
"15712", "15713", "15714", "15715", "15716", "15717", "15718", 
"15719", "15720", "15721", "15722", "15723", "15724", "15725", 
"15726", "15727", "15728", "15729", "15730", "15731"), class = "data.frame")
```

I wish I've made myself clear I think there must be a simpler way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: I think the problem is a parity one.  t_entre/t_muestreo=12.5 and sometimes I need it to be 12 and thus I correct with -0.5 but other times I need it to be 13 and I'm not correcting it so I get the out of phase subset. Is there a way to compute when it should be 12 or 13 ?

Comment: how do you determine when it should be 12 or 13? you could use  one of `floor(12.5); ceiling(12.5); round(12.5)` depending on what you need

Comment: In this example there are 4 df to be subseted and calculated. Notice that the space between the first two dfs should be 11 but the second one should be 12. Between the 3rd and 4th there should be 11 and between the 4th and 5th (in this case there is no 5th) there should be 12.

Answer (score 0):

I think the for loop is just subsetting and applying the function `ibtener_pendientes`. If that is the case you can use this:

```
## create list of dfs based on row idx
idx <- list(1:11, 23:33, 45:56, 67:78)
## or write a function to automate the rows
# idx <- lapply(seq(1, nrow(d), by = 10 + 12), function(x) seq(x, x + 11))
l <- lapply(idx, function(x) d[x, ])
do.call('rbind', Map('obtener_pendientes', l))


#                   tiempo        V2         V3  V4          V5         V6
# df_a_medir$tiempo      1 8.2272727 37.9090909   0  95.5909091 16.6818182
#                        1 0.9495273  0.7936207 NaN   0.8618870  0.5851504
# df_a_medir$tiempo      1 2.3181818 50.3181818   0 184.8636364 10.6363636
#                        1 0.9436334  0.8228418 NaN   0.9712757  0.9353285
# df_a_medir$tiempo      1 0.0000000  4.4220779   0  51.0649351  1.4675325
#                        1       NaN  0.8718034 NaN   0.7925802  0.6962431
# df_a_medir$tiempo      1 0.0000000  4.0000000   0 194.3636364  1.9090909
#                        1       NaN  0.5621631 NaN   0.9699970  0.7561455
#                           V7          V8        V9       V10         V11
# df_a_medir$tiempo  8.4090909 182.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000  77.0454545
#                    0.9803865   0.9748662       NaN       NaN   0.8338448
# df_a_medir$tiempo 10.4090909 169.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 242.1363636
#                    0.9862105   0.9684383       NaN       NaN   0.9918088
# df_a_medir$tiempo  0.0000000 120.2272727 0.0000000 1.6818182  36.2532468
#                          NaN   0.9357959       NaN 0.8381040   0.8932908
# df_a_medir$tiempo  0.0000000 165.5000000 5.8636364 2.6363636 171.0909091
#                          NaN   0.9730404 0.9418502 0.9271605   0.9658712
#                         V12        V13       V14        V15 V16 V17       V18
# df_a_medir$tiempo 0.7727273 86.1363636 9.8636364 27.8181818   0   0 2.2727273
#                   0.5311111  0.9337161 0.8997295  0.8450071 NaN NaN 0.8739165
# df_a_medir$tiempo 0.0000000 77.2727273 4.9545455 20.1363636   0   0 9.0454545
#                         NaN  0.9727717 0.7449921  0.9362205 NaN NaN 0.9558411
# df_a_medir$tiempo 0.0000000 52.7532468 0.3571429  5.7337662   0   0 0.0000000
#                         NaN  0.8280456 0.7368421  0.8605300 NaN NaN       NaN
# df_a_medir$tiempo 0.0000000 68.8181818 0.6363636 18.5454545   0   0 0.0000000
#                         NaN  0.9035839 0.6666667  0.9262417 NaN NaN       NaN
#                         V19 V20       V21
# df_a_medir$tiempo 0.0000000   0 3.5000000
#                         NaN NaN 0.8115468
# df_a_medir$tiempo 2.8636364   0 7.6363636
#                   0.9541063 NaN 0.9702682
# df_a_medir$tiempo 0.0000000   0 0.3571429
#                         NaN NaN 0.7368421
# df_a_medir$tiempo 0.0000000   0 0.0000000
#                         NaN NaN       NaN
```

which looks similar to the output I got from your loop function

helper functions:
(didnt have enough room to add the data `d` here)

```
regresion <- function(formula){ 
  regresion = lm( formula )
  ss = summary(regresion)
  return(c( coef(regresion)[2] , ss$adj.r.squared))
}

sacar_columnas <- function (dataframe,columnas){
  return(dataframe[,!(names(dataframe) %in% columnas)])
}

desplazar<- function(tiempo,dataframe){
  matriz = as.matrix(dataframe)
  matriz_dif = abs(diff(matriz )) # derivar
  matriz_dif_inv = diffinv(matriz_dif) # integrar

  return(data.frame(cbind(tiempo, matriz_dif_inv )))
}

obtener_pendientes <- function(df_a_medir){
  df_a_medir2 =sacar_columnas(df_a_medir,  c("estado","tiempo"))
  mat_desplazamiento = desplazar(df_a_medir$tiempo,df_a_medir2)
  pend_muestreo = apply(mat_desplazamiento,2,function(x) regresion(x~df_a_medir$tiempo))  
  return(pend_muestreo)
}
```

Comment: The fact is i don't want to type the row number because the number of dfs to subset usually changes. In this case the total is 4 but it is usually 6 or even 30. In the last case, keeping the correct 30 dfs correctly it's just the thing I'm trying to avoid (I used to subset by time column and I'm trying to change that because it introduces user errors)

Comment: I mean, you don't have to do that either. you said there was a pattern ... so write a function: `idx <- lapply(seq(1, nrow(d), by = 10 + 12), function(x) seq(x, x + 11))`

Comment: This doesn't work well. I get 5 data frames in a list. Each one with 12 obs. Besides, they're not correct subsets. check your idx list, it hasn't got the correct numbers

Comment: so tweak the numbers, haha. maybe it will be `x + 10` or something. Or should I just do it all for you? I get 1:11, 23:33, 45:55, etc. You said there was a pattern. Replicate the pattern to get the proper row indices, and *then* start using the rest of this answer.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the notation seq (..., by= 10 + 12). I was checking seq help but it doesn't explain the adding thing in by. I will. In fact i'm not asking for you to do all, you only wrote 2 lines of code which doesn't work so you could be more gentle.

Comment: 1:n is short for seq(1, n, by = 1), so seq(..., by = 10 + 12) is making jumps from the starting position, 1, to the end by jumps of 22. I chose this because you want 10 (or 11 or whatever rows) but you also want to skip 12, so the *next* starting position will be the current, 1, plus the rows you want plus the rows you dont, 10 + 12. And again you want x number of rows, so you can use seq again, `seq(start, x)` which is the same as `start:x`